# Fix a mistakenly bound key in Tmux

Tags: vim, key, tmux

**Here is Tmux topic for key mapping.**

Two days ago, I wanted to change the key mapping to swap windows, so I changed `.tmux.conf` file to include the following:

```
bind-key -n P swap-window -t -1
bind-key -n N swap-window -t +1
```

My intent was that typing **prefix + N** swaps the current focused window for the next window and also typing **prefix + P** swaps the current window fir the previous window.

I applied it with `:source ~/.tmux.conf`

Immediately after I changed as that, I delete the two line in `.tmux.conf` to undo its setting.

Now, my `N` and `P` keys are dead. (lower case `n` and `p` can work)

How can I make N or P key available?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two questions, so I'll answer both.

#### How can I bind `prefix + N` / `prefix + P`?

Don't use `-n` if you want the `prefix` part to be required. In your `tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key P swap-window -t -1
bind-key N swap-window -t +1
```

The `-n` stands for "no prefix".

#### How can I fix a binding mistake?

Use `unbind`, the opposite of `bind`. In your terminal:

```
<prefix>:unbind-key -n P
<prefix>:unbind-key -n N
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Saved my rear.